# Advanced Linear

Tags: linear-algebra

An involution is a linear transformation $φ ∈ L(V, V )$ such that $φ^2 = Id_V$ . Show that the equation $φ = 2π−Id_V$ establishes a one-to-one correspondence between all projections $π$ and all involutions $φ$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Hint: $\varphi^2=(2\pi - Id_V)^2=4\pi^2-4\pi+Id_V$

Answer (score 0):

If

$\pi:V \to V \tag 1$

is a projection, then

$\pi^2 = \pi; \tag 2$

if we set

$\phi = 2\pi - I, \tag 3$

we have

$\phi^2 = (2\pi - I)(2\pi - I) = 4\pi^2 - 4\pi + I = 4\pi - 4\pi + I = I, \tag 4$

so $\phi$ is an involution on $V$.

Likewise, if $\phi$ is an involution and (3) holds for some $\pi \in L(V, V)$, then

$4\pi^2 - 4\pi + I = (2\pi - I)(2\pi - I) = \phi^2 = I, \tag 5$

whence

$4\pi^2 - 4\pi = 0 \Longrightarrow 4\pi^2 = 4\pi \Longrightarrow \pi^2 = \pi, \tag 6$

so $\pi$ is a projection.

For every projection $\pi$, (3) defines and involution, and for every involution, (3) defines a projection, ***viz.***

$\pi = \dfrac{1}{2}(\phi + I); \tag 7$

indeed this gives us

$\pi^2 = \dfrac{1}{4}(\phi + I)(\phi + I) = \dfrac{1}{4}(\phi^2 + 2\phi + I)$
$= \dfrac{1}{4}(I + 2\phi + I) = \dfrac{1}{4}(2\phi + 2I) = \dfrac{1}{2}(\phi + I) = \pi. \tag 8$

The mappings (3) and (7) are each clearly one-to-one, for

$\phi = 2\pi_1 - I = 2\pi_2 - I \Longrightarrow 2\pi_1 = 2\pi_2 \Longrightarrow \pi_1 = \pi_2, \tag 9$

and

$\pi = \dfrac{1}{2}(\phi_1 + I) = \dfrac{1}{2}(\phi_2 + I) \Longrightarrow \phi_1 + I = \phi_2 + I \Longrightarrow \phi_1 = \phi_2. \tag{10}$